# Definition of chain homotopic.

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $C_{\bullet}, D_{\bullet}$ be two nonnegatively graded chain complexs of $R$-modules with maps $d^C,d^D$ respectively($d^C_n: C_{n+1} \to C_n$), and let $f,g: C_{\bullet} \to D_{\bullet}$ be two chain maps. Then, a chain homotopy from $f$ to $g$ is a sequence of $R$-linear maps $h_n: C_{n-1} \to D_{n}$ such that $$f_n - g_n = d^D_{n}h_{n+1} + h_{n}d^{C}_{n-1}.$$

First of all, is my definition correct? My second question is, what does this really mean? My notes say that if such a chain homotopy exist then we say that $f$ and $g$ are chain homotopic and we write $f \cong g$. I feel that the definition is some kind of "isomorphism" between two chain maps but I cant see how, can someone explain what it really means to have a chain homotopy, i cant really "unfold" the definition.

Comment: Consider $f_n - g_n - h_nd_{n-1}^C = d_n^Dh_{n+1}$. Observe that the left hand side is a cycle which is a boundary of $h_{n+1}$. In other words, $f_n, g_n$ are parts of the cycle, $f_n - g_n - h_nd_{n-1}^C$. The term $- h_nd_{n-1}^C$ basically fills the missing part so that $f_n - g_n - h_nd_{n-1}^C$ becomes a cycle.

Answer (score 3):

I would post this as a comment but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation at the moment. 
Yes, your definition is correct, as is your appearent intuition. Chain homotopies are a concept which originates from topology, where the complexes at hand are usually motivated by a decomposition of a topological space into cells (CW-complexes), simplices (simplicial complexes) or continuous deformations of simplicies (singular homology) hence the nomenclature. And what you suspect is true: chain homotopies are *somewhat* related to isomorphisms of chain complexes. Given two maps {$f_n$}$_n$ and {$g_n$}$_n$ between chain complexes $C_*$ and $D_*$ which are chain homotopic (i.e. there exists a chain homotopy between them), then they induce the same map after passing to homology.
Their importance comes from the idea that what you would expect an *isomorphism of chain complexes* to be (namely a level-wise isomorphism which commutes with differentials) is a very restrictive definition. Instead, what one considers is *quasi-isomorphisms*, which are morphisms of chain complexes which induce isomorphisms in homology. And this is precisely where chain homotopies come in handy as not all quasi-isomorphisms must necessarily be given by isomorphisms of chain complexes.